# Paperclip sharpening processor causes resizing styles not to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to sharpen images uploaded through paperclip. The sharpen code is working but it causes the styles to not work. The code is like this:

```
 has_attached_file :photo,
    :styles => {
                :thumb => {:geometry => "100x100>"},
                :medium => {:geometry => "300x300>"},
                :original => {:geometry => "1024x1024>"}
                },
    :processors => [:sharpen],
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
    :path => "/:style/:id/:filename"
```

Now if I remove the processors option, the uploaded images are resized as specified. However if I include the processors option, all the resulting images are of original size.

My sharpen processor looks like this:

```
module Paperclip
  class Sharpen < Paperclip::Processor
    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @file = file
      @current_format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @current_format)
    end

    def make
      dst = Tempfile.new(@basename)
      dst.binmode

      command = "#{File.expand_path(@file.path)} -unsharp 1.5×1.0+1.5+0.02 #{File.expand_path(dst.path)}"

      begin
        success = Paperclip.run("convert", command)
      rescue PaperclipCommandLineError
        raise PaperclipError, "There was an error converting sharpening the image for #{@basename}"
      end

      dst
    end
  end
end
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `:thumbnail` to processors list:

```
:processors => [:thumbnail, :sharpen]
```

By default `:thumbnail` is there but now you are overriding that setting.

"Multiple processors can be specified, and they will be invoked in the order they are defined in the :processors array. Each successive processor will be given the result of the previous processor's execution. All processors will receive the same parameters, which are what you define in the :styles hash."

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: Awesome, it worked! I really didn't notice that thumbnail processor would be executed by default. Thanks man.