# RoR ImageMagick/Paperclip --- Why is the image quality reduced when resized?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm having issues with ImageMagick resizing the image, and making it blurry/fuzzy. Here is the original image:

[link to original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbAbc.png)

But here is what it is looking like when resized:

https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lexody/app/public/translations/images/23/Once_you_find_someone_to_meet_with.png?1499357259

QUESTION: Why is the quality changing when resized?

I have a table called Translations that includes a text and an image. A user uploads the image with this form:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "English Text (to be translated in target language)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :english_text %>
    <h1>Upload Image</h1>
    <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
```

I am using ImageMagick to resize the images:

```
class Translation < ApplicationRecord

if Rails.env.production?
  .....
else
    has_attached_file :image, :source_file_options => { :all => '-auto-orient' }, :styles => {
                    thumb: '100x100>',
                    square: '200x200>',
                    medium: '300x300>'
                  }

end
validates_attachment :image,
                 content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
end
```

Displaying the image...

HTML:

```
<div class="translation_img_and_instructions">
    <% if session[:@trans_sample].image.url != "/images/original/missing.png" %>
        <%= image_tag session[:@trans_sample].image.url(:square), class: "translation_img" %>
    <% end %>
    <h1>Translate into <%= @sessionLang["language"] %>:</h1>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.translation_img', function() {
var thumbUrl = $(this).attr('src');
//console.log(this)
var origUrl = thumbUrl.replace('square', 'original');

if (thumbUrl.indexOf('missing') > -1) {
    origUrl = '/assets/medium/missing.png';
}

console.log(origUrl);

var thumbPosition = $(this).offset();

$('body').append('<div class="closeBigPic"></div><div class="bigPicWrapper translationImg"><img class="bigPic" src="' + origUrl + '" /></div>')

$('.bigPicWrapper')
    .css('top', thumbPosition.top)
    .css('left', thumbPosition.left);
$('.bigPicWrapper').animate({
    top: '35%',
    left: '35%',
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    marginTop: -100,
    marginLeft: -100
}, 300);
```

});

When the image is uploaded and resized, the quality is significantly reduced..

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Maybe you should choose a resample filter here http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#filter for your image?

Comment: You can try to sharpen them as well, either pre-resize or post resize - this should result in crispier images. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801905/paperclip-sharpening-processor-causes-resizing-styles-not-to-work but eventually you have to accept that downsizing an image is exactly that, ditching pixels, so the quality always suffers. If you do it in Photoshop, it has probably thousands upon thousands of hours just poured on the resizing algorithm, so it will produce better results. Still, usually you need to trick the eye by applying a bit of sharpening so the pixel loss doesn't show

Comment: "I am using ImageMagick to resize the images:" I can not see any Imagemagick code. I assume it is in the class? I do not see how we can offer suggestions without the code. Most of the code you have posted is of no help with answering the question.

Comment: I would second the comment by Bonzo. Your results look fine to me for the amount of shrinking of the image. Small text will never be sharp when you shrink a considerable amount.  But you can try -filter carton -resize and see if that helps further.